# How to change the design of the default datepicker calendar with Javascript

Tags: javascript, date, calendar, chatbot

We are creating a chat bot with an already made API. And we need the customers to choose their birth date from a calendar. So the we made that possible was with the JavaScript default date function, which gives us only the default old design of the calendar.

[image: picture]:

So we tried Customizing and Theming jQuery UI Datepicker (https://www.hongkiat.com/blog/jquery-ui-datepicker/?fbclid=IwAR3iOB10MghttQIgosrp0wnR9HVJCRbWQSxWoJYqtrAY81F_CrLsK7nKyo4)
Also tried to do that with html and CSS, but didn't succeed.

```js
var tutorial = function ()
{
    //
    homeBot.message.add({
        delay: 1000,
        content: "Внесете датум на раѓање"
    }).then(function () {
        return homeBot.action.text({
            delay: 800,
            action: {
            value: 'Date',
            sub_type: 'Date'
        }
    });
})
```

So with this code we are getting the result shown on the picture (attached above)

And the Html code

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Мапи</title>
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1"/>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
        <script src="script.js"></script><link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="stil.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="datepicker.min.css">

        <meta name="google-site-verification" content="s9xp_mKgHJJvR0EO39LQkXtuPaEfKkFH1Ao18efqwzU" />
    </head>

    <body style="background-image: url('mapipozadina.png'); background-repeat: no-repeat;">
        <div class="botui-app-container" id="home-demo">
            <bot-ui>  </bot-ui>
        </div>

        <script src="js.js"></script>
        <script src="util.js"></script>
        <script>
            if (window.location.hostname.indexOf("botui.org") === 0) { // don't track local dev visits
              (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
              (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
              m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
              })(window,document,'script','analytic.js','ga');

              ga('create', 'UA-102158265-2', 'auto');
              ga('send', 'pageview');
            } else {
              window.ga = false;
            }
        </script>
        <script src="datepicker.min.js"></script>

        <script src="bot.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: There doesn't appear to be a question. Please see [*How do I ask a good question?*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: The question is, does anyone know how to change the design of the calendar with javascript?